# how to update 200 instances of an application with git

Tags: git

We have a system with 200 instances of a custom application.

These are always updated in the deployment window every 2 weeks.

The problem we have is that this process takes a long time and the more instances are added, the longer it would take.

The repository has grown to a size of 400 MB.

A maximum of 2 commits are deployed per deployment as we squash most of it.

Script:

```sh
for application in $applications
do
        cd "/var/www/$application"
        git pull origin master
done
```

The question now is how can we speed up the process?

Comment: maybe you can pull them concurrently? but then the bottleneck might be network and disk IO then

Answer (score 0):

You could have one local copy that is linked to the remote, and then all the others "pull" from the local copy. You can make a repo with a local remote by doing `git clone file://path/to/repo`. That way, you'll only need to fetch from the internet once. You might be able to speed it up even further by doing things concurrently like @Kristian suggested, but I'm almost entirely certain that you'll be bottlenecked by IO.